# How to Access Longlistselector children object in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

How can i get access to longlistselector items.

My XAML is:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="30,20,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
  <phone:LongListSelector Name="longList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="210" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="210" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="160" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Name="first" Width="210" Margin="0" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
          <Image Name="second" Width="210" Margin="0" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
  </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

I want to get access of image objects **first** & **second**

I need to assign source of these two image objects from list of class which contain **ImageName** string as variable(holds path of jpg image) consecutive and then next two to next row and so on..

Comment: i just need need to set image source first.

Comment: this demo will show you how to populate a longlistselector in WP8 http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth

Answer (score 0):

Add a new folder to the solution and rename the folder to "Model"

Then add a new class with the name "ImageSourceClass"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp.Model
{
    public class ImageSourceClass
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public ImageSourceClass(string imageUrl)
        {
            this.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
    }

    public class ImageData : ObservableCollection<ImageSourceClass>
    {
        public ImageData()
        {
            Add(new ImageSourceClass("/Assets/Images/Fruits.jpg"));
            Add(new ImageSourceClass("/Assets/Images/Beignets.jpg"));
            Add(new ImageSourceClass("/Assets/Images/Dessert.jpg"));
            Add(new ImageSourceClass("/Assets/Images/Pretzel.jpg"));
            Add(new ImageSourceClass("/Assets/Images/Shrimp.jpg"));
            Add(new ImageSourceClass("/Assets/Images/SteakSandwich.jpg"));
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

Added the below namespace to MainPage.xaml

Note : [According to your solution name namespace may vary]

xmlns:MyModel="clr-namespace:TestApp.Model"

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
<Grid.Resources>
      <MyModel:ImageData x:Key="imageDatasource"></MyModel:ImageData>
</Grid.Resources>
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lstRestoItems" ItemsSource="{StaticResource imageDatasource}" LayoutMode="List">
     <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="100" Width="100"         HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
     </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>

</Grid>
```

We are done , now just clean and re-build your application and press f5